# SQL Select case - am I using it right?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to do a select, which calculates different values depending on one controlled value (let's name it value1). I am trying to calculate time difference between two values.

Table 'test' looks like this (I do not have create table statements, I'm just extracting and simplyfying contents of live database):

```
value1 | value2              | value3              |value4
PO     | 2017-06-20 21:54:00 | 2017-06-20 21:24:00 |2017-06-20 08:21:00
HOS    | 2017-06-20 21:54:00 | 2017-06-20 21:24:00 |2017-06-20 08:21:00

select case
  WHEN test.value1 = 'PO' 
     THEN (test.value2-test.value3)
     ELSE (test.value2-test.value4)
  END as "Time"
  from test
```

I am getting error:

```
ERROR: CASE types timestamp without time zone and interval cannot be matched
```

So in brief, if value1 equals 'A', then I want to substract values 2 and 3. Value1 is string, values2, 3 and 4 are dates with time.

Am I understanding case wrong?

edit: Ok, I'm a little retarded sometimes, my issue was that the value4 was string, so I had to select it again with `select to_timestamp`

Comment: `FROM table_name` is missing. Please add it and also share complete table structure on which you want to run this query

Comment: If `value2`, `value3` and `value4` are all defined as `timestamp` this should work. Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the table in question. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - [edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: from the error, your code should be different

Answer (score 0):

The `value3` and `value4` column's types are not the some nor convertible to a single type. The error message states this clearly.

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-conditional.html):

> The data types of all the result expressions must be convertible to a
>   single output type.

When working with date and time values in postgres, the subtract operator can result various (inconvertible) types. [Table 9-27](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html)